# How to show message to user if they are trying to leave the page or close the window only if form data has been changed?

Tags: javascript, browser, onbeforeunload

I have requirement in one of my projects where users would like to see a message before they leave the page or close the browser/window if the form data has been changed. I found this function that will catch the scenario if user is leaving the window or closing the browser.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = '';
});
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to show that message only if form data has been changed. SO user in that case would know that data has changed. I did not find a lot about this topic or any constructive solutions so far. If anyone have any examples or suggestions please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using any modern framework you can build your custom Form State helper.
When form is ready on DOM you can iterate over each input element and assign a data property say (data-init-val) and set its value equal to the input element value.

```
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('form#userform input');
for(let inputEl of inputs){
    inputEl.setAttribute('oldVal', inputEl.value);
}
```

This way you're caching the existing form values. When user is closing the window you can run a function to compare current input values with the initial cached values via:

```
function checkFormState(){
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('form#userform input');
  let stateChanged = false;
  for(let inputEl of inputs){
    if(inputEl.getAttribute('oldVal') !== inputEl.value){
        stateChanged = true;
        break;
    }
  }

  return stateChanged;
}
```

Your eventListener can make an informed decision based on the stateChanged value.
PS: You should modify the input element value caching/compare logic based on the input elements in your form.

Headover to https://jsfiddle.net/v9rztay6/ and see it in action.